# How to avoid unnecessary re-renders due to passing functions through props to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to debug a component that seems to render more times than I'm expecting and so I installed `why-did-you-render`.  The error `different functions with the same name. (more info at some site)` led me to this article explaining the issue, https://medium.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render-mr-big-pure-react-component-part-2-common-fixing-scenarios-667bfdec2e0f.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to address this issue.  The component looks like this

```
const Comp = ({cb}) => <div onClick={cb}>click me</div>
```

and it would be used like so:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const cb = () => console.log('clicked!!!')
  return <div><Comp cb={cb} /></div>
}
```

EDIT:
more precisely, I have an issue where I have a higher order component where I generate a function that I pass via props and was wondering how I can avoid this issue:

```
// the HoC
const HoC = Component => {
  const cb = makeFn();
  return <div><Component cb={cb} />
}
```

// a component that uses the HoC with the above component

```
const Top = () => {
  return <HoC Component={Comp} />
}
```

when I try to use `useCallback` I get an error message `React Hook "useCallback" is called in function Top which is neither a React function or a custom React hook function`

Comment: Move `cb` declaration out of the `const Parent` function body, so that it always was just a single `cb` instance.

Comment: that wont work if the method needs access to props or state.

Comment: if the method needs access to props or state then it _should_ rerender

Answer (score 1):

You will need to memoize the call back.
read more about the details in the react docs.

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
const Child = React.memo(function({cb}) {
  <div onClick={cb}>click me</div>
});


const Parent = () => {
  const memoizedCallback = React.useCallback(
      () => console.log('clicked!!!'),
      [/*dependencies here*/],
    );
  return <div><Comp cb={memoizedCallback} /></div>
}
```

By using React memo you are making your component check old props and new props to see if anything changes. And since we are memoizing the callback we are sending in, it will have the same pointer from the previous render resulting in no extra re-render.

Comment: so I wouldn't be using _either_ React.memo _or_ useCallback but need to use both?

Comment: Yes, so we need useCallback to preserve the callback reference we are passing down, since the callback gets re-created on every parent re-render. and by default react components do not check if they should re-render when a parent updates they just go ahead and re-render. To stop that re-render we need to make it either a pureComponent (for class based) or react.memo for comps as functions. And what that will do is diff the previous props with the current props, and if they are different the component will re-render.

Comment: but since we memoized the callback on the parent, when the child gets the callback, it will notice the previous callback is the same as the one we are just passing in so it will know not to update. There are caveats with useCallback, but you can read all about how to use it from the docs. Make sure your dependency array is accurate and any props/state used in the callback is listed in the dependency array.

Comment: will mapping dispatch to props through react-redux's connect function trigger a number of re-renders since this is effectively doing the same passing of functions through props?